# jQuery click event handler for dynamically created UL is not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have UL list with jQuery connected sortable functionality, trying to achieve the connected sortable with multiple item select & dragging.

In my page user can create UL list dynamically and I am creating the dynamic UL list inside the DIV control. In document.ready() function I have attaching click event handlers to UL controls. But this handler is not attaching to the UL controls created inside DIV. Why?

I have attached the Fiddle sample as well.

Any help

```
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EN2P5/2/
```

Comment: If you want to include a link to JSfiddle, you also have to show some code.

Comment: Yes I added the JSFiddle link

Comment: The idea is that you post at least some of your code in addition to the JSFiddle link.  Stack Overflow is meant to be a long-term resource, so having code posted here is a priority.

Comment: I added one full sample code in JSFiddle. Please let me know what else you need to add in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with the `.live()` method which is now used this way since the `.on()` function exists :

```
$(document).on('click', 'ul li', function (e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) {
        $(this).toggleClass("selected");
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass('selected');
    }
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EN2P5/8/

Comment: Thanks for your answer! After your change the selection is working but sortable functionality is not working.

Comment: I updated the fiddleJs, didn't see that the list had a sortable event :P

Comment: Then you can create a function with you dragging logic and affect it to your newly created `<ul>`. JsFiddle updated

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `on`function when binding generated DOM elements.

```
$("ul").on("click", function(){
   console.log("click");
});
```

You could also use `bind`, `delegate`.

Comment: Actually, I believe `.on` is the proper handler to use nowadays

Comment: Its not working. The only problem is click event is not working only for controls created inside the DIV.  

I agree with Collin, we have to use .on as for latest jQuery version.